# UIButton within Table View Cell issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having issues with my button that is located in side my UITableViewCell. I'm using storyboard and connected my button through IB. Within my cellforRowatIndexPath I added an action to my button:

```
cell.likeBtnPressed.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.likeBtnPressed addTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTapOnLikeButton:photo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Below you will see what is called when the button is pressed:

```
-(void)userDidTapOnLikeButton:(UIButton *)button photo:(PFObject *)photo{
    //Disable the button so users cannot send duplicat requests
    [button setEnabled:NO];
    [button setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];


    //Set the new state of the button
    BOOL liked = !button.selected;
    [button setEnabled:liked];

    //Get the current number of likes the post have
    NSString *originalButtonTitle = button.titleLabel.text;
    NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [numberFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];

    //Update the like count in the ECDCache
    NSNumber *likeCount = [numberFormatter numberFromString:button.titleLabel.text];
    if (liked) {
        likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] + 1];
        [[ECDCache sharedCache] incrementLikerCountForPhoto:photo];
    }else{
        if ([likeCount intValue] > 0) {
            likeCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[likeCount intValue] - 1];
        }

        [[ECDCache sharedCache] decrementLikerCountForPhoto:photo];
    }

    //Add the current user as a liker of the photo in ECDCache
    [[ECDCache sharedCache] setPhotoIsLikedByCurrentUser:photo liked:liked];

    //Update the button label
    [button setTitle:[numberFormatter stringFromNumber:likeCount] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    //Call the appropriate static method to handle creating/deleting the right object
    if (liked) {
        [ECDUtility likePhotoInBackground:photo block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            [button setEnabled:YES];
            [button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
            [[button titleLabel] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0.0f, -1.0f)];

            if (!succeeded) {
                // Revert the button title (the number) if the call fails
                [button setTitle:originalButtonTitle forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

When ever I press the button I receive this:

```
-[UITouchesEvent objectId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x15ee5de0
```

I'm not sure what I did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the second parameter your method is receiving is not a `PFObject`, but a `UIEvent`.

There are three types of selectors you can send into `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`:

- **`@selector(a)`**: This method takes no parameters.
- **`@selector(a:)`**: This method has one parameter which is the `UIControl` which received the control event.
- **`@selector(a:b:)`**: This method has two parameters, the `UIControl` which received the control event, and the `UIEvent` that triggered it.

Since you are only looking to get the button, you should have a signature like this:

```
-(void)userDidTapOnLikeButton:(UIButton *)button
{
    PFObject *photo = [self someLogicToGetThePhotoFromTheButton:button];
    ...
```

Comment: Okay I will try this out. Is there a way for me to retrieve the index path for the button within my userDidtap.. method?

Comment: You take `button` and look at its `superview` (and maybe the superview's superview) to get the `UITableViewCell` that contains it.  Then you just need `-[UITableView indexPathForCell:]`.

Comment: Theoretically, you could use the `UIEvent` parameter from the `@selector(a:b:)` option along with `-[UITableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:]` to get the index path. `[tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[event.allTouches.anyObject locationInView:tableView]]`

Answer (score 0):

you can't add a target with more than one parameter in UIButton selector. When the selector is called receive only the sender parameter, in that case, the UIButton object. So I recommend that you use:

```
[cell.likeBtnPressed addTarget:self action:@selector(userDidTapOnLikeButton:photo:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

-(void)userDidTapOnLikeButton:(id)sender{
  //Your code
}
```

And then retrieve the photo using the tag of the cell for example.

Good luck ;)

Comment: Technically, you can have two parameters, but the second parameter is a `UIEvent`